# Swift: getting incorrect result when dealing with Intersection of Two Linked Lists

Tags: swift, algorithm, linked-list

I try to work on a leetcode problem: `Intersection of Two Linked Lists`. I follow a valid solution in Java and rewrite it in Swift and playground because leetcode doesn't allow me to change their predefine `ListNode` model so it always Compile Failed. However, unlucky it returns Node(1) in my code below but not expected Node(8).

I did Googles and checks, and think the problem should be on the comparison of two object `while ha != hb`. But I simply stuck at here and cannot tackle it, could you give me some hint.

[image]

```
// Intersection of linked list
// Definition for singly-linked list.
public class ListNode: Equatable {
    public var val: Int
    public var next: ListNode?
    public init(_ val: Int) {
        self.val = val
        self.next = nil
    }
    
    public static func == (lhs: ListNode, rhs: ListNode) -> Bool {
        return lhs.val == rhs.val && rhs.next == rhs.next
    }
}

var hA = ListNode(4)
hA.next = ListNode(1)
let node8 = ListNode(8)
let node4 = ListNode(4)
let node5 = ListNode(5)
hA.next?.next = node8
hA.next?.next?.next = node4
hA.next?.next?.next?.next = node5

var hB = ListNode(5)
hB.next = ListNode(6)
hB.next?.next = ListNode(1)
hB.next?.next?.next = node8
hB.next?.next?.next?.next = node4
hB.next?.next?.next?.next?.next = node5


class Solution {
    func getIntersectionNode(_ headA: ListNode?, _ headB: ListNode?) -> ListNode? {
        if headA == nil || headB == nil {
            return nil
        }

        var ha = headA
        var hb = headB

        while ha != hb {
            ha = ha == nil ? headB : ha?.next
            hb = hb == nil ? headA : hb?.next
        }

        return ha
    }
}

Solution().getIntersectionNode(hA, hB)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to distinguish between node “1” of list A and “1” of list B. It means that your get intersection function does not go past that check.

Comment: Yes, that works! Add a `UUID` property could create unique instance and I could add a comparison judgment on method `==` too.

Comment: where to add UUID?